# Sometimes memo/clob field forces a new page

Tags: crystal-reports

In Details G, I have a text object called *Note.* Below that in Details H is a datatype *Memo* which gets a clob field from the database.

I always want to show *Memo* directly below *Note*, but sometimes Details H starts from new page - even though G ends in the middle of the page and there should be plenty of room for H. How can I fix this?

Checking *Keep Together* for the details section didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Keep Together` can't keep objects together that won't fit on one page. They may not fit because of border settings, white-space in your Memo field or other things.

Allow your Memo field to be splitted up - uncheck `Keep Object Together` in the Format Editor of the Memo field. This will let it start right below the previous section - even if it won't fit on the page.

[image: Screenshot Format Editor]

Also make sure that you haven't checked `New Page Before` in the section properties of the section containing the Memo.